# Unexpected behaviour when calling serializer.create method, causes data loss in unrelated data (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
Django>=4.2.7,<4.3.0
djangorestframework>=3.14.0,<3.15.0
python-dateutil>=2.8.2,<2.9.0
psycopg2-binary>=2.9.9,<3.0.0
django-crontab>=0.7.1,<0.8.0
```

Im writing a tests for the serializer.create method. I prepared some data to pass it to the create method

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    """
    Passing in the restructured validated_data to the
    CostumUserCreate method.
    """
    user_data = validated_data.get('user_data')
    profile_data = validated_data.get('profile_data')

    new_user = User.objects.create(
        user_data=user_data,
        profile_data=profile_data
    )

    return new_user
```

my test:

```
def test_serializer_create(self):
    """
    Tests the correct restructuring of the validated data within
    the CustomUserSerializer create method.
    """
    data = {}
    user_data = {
        'email': 'updated.email@GMAIL.com',  # Not normalized
        'password': 'blabla123'
    }

    profile_data = {
        'first_name': 'Jay',
        'last_name': 'Miller',
        'position': self.position1
    }

    data['user_data'] = user_data
    data['profile_data'] = profile_data

    serializer = serializers.CustomUserSerializer()
    user = serializer.create(data)

    print(f'USER DATA: {user_data}')
    print(f'PROFILE DATA: {profile_data}')
```

when I try to print the `user_data` and `profile_data` now into the console it will be printed as an empty dictionary in the case of the `user_data` but not for the profile_data
`USER DATA: {}`
`PROFILE DATA: {'first_name': 'Jay', 'last_name': 'Miller', 'position': <Position: Human Resource Specialist>}`

but as soon as I comment out the `serializer.create` method the user_data appears again in the terminal

`USER DATA: {'email': 'updated.email@GMAIL.com', 'password': 'blabla123'}`
`PROFILE DATA: {'first_name': 'Jay', 'last_name': 'Miller', 'position': <Position: Human Resource Specialist>}`

I have no idea how this can even happen since the serializer.create method or therefore any method shouldn't be able to have any effect on the variables that are accessed before being passed into them...or did I understand something wrong here?

I literally have no idea how to fix this I tried to google it, `chatgpt` it but I still haven't even a clue of whats happening here.

Comment: I am guessing you've got the scenario backwards and that you get the output with your code but not when commented. But I can't confirm since you've not provided us a [mre].

Comment: I'm actually not, it's exactly as I described it. I will try to provide the minimal reproducible example as soon as I can but it's literally just a serializers.Serializer. Create() tested within an APITestCase with  2 nested dictionaries within a main dictionary passed into Serializer. Create(). I'm not using the return value of it or anything like that, just the fact that I'm calling the method causes the user_data to become an empty dictionary.Meanwhile the profile_data is not effected at all...as it's supposed to

Comment: Why are you calling `create` on the serializer? The `Serializer` class is constructed in a way that when you pass an instance of a model into it, it automatically calls `update` however when you pass data from a POST request, it automatically calls `create`. Therefore it seems to me that you ONLY need to call `serializer.save()`. Or, maybe I'm missing something... But the correct way to implement this is `CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)` or `CustomUserSerializer(instance=model_instance)`

Comment: yes what you are saying is true, and maybe my approach is the actual problem. I have to say that im new to django and relatively new to programming itself(learning it for about 9 months). i recently started to implement test driven development and what im essentially doing is testing all my classes thoroughly , so that my tests when failing can show me immediately where the error occured, down to the very methods. like i said maybe this is the problem that causes this behaviour in my code to begin with ?

Comment: guys i just wanted to inform you that the problem got solved, after doing some more research ive come to the conclusion that my approach was wrong to begin with. it was pretty much inefficient and i restructured alot of my testing code. thank you to everyone for your help